# XSLT Check the presence of a substring and then print if exist

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Consider the following XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire_Burlesque_something</title>
    <title>Empire_Burlesque_other</title>
    <title>Home_Empire_Burlesque</title>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

The desired output would be something like this:

```
Empire: Empire_Burlesque_something;Empire_Burlesque_other;
Home: Home_Empire_Burlesque
```

What's being done here is, as evident, we are selecting the first word (before the first "_") from every input string and marking it as a **substring**. Then this substring would be checked against all the input strings to see if it exists, and if it does, concatenate all the strings if they contain the substring and further prepend that with the **substring**. Repeat this procedure with all the substrings against every input string.

Here's what I have written until now (Yes, it could be way much better and simple and all other things but this is me trying to first get the desired output)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:variable name="key">
  <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd/title">
<value>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(current(),'_')" />
</value>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="abc">
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(($key)/value)">
<value>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
</value>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="value">
  <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd/title">
    <value>
      <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
    </value>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
<h4><xsl:value-of select="$abc" /></h4>
<h4><xsl:value-of select="$key" /></h4>
    <h4>
      <xsl:for-each select="($abc)/value">
<xsl:variable name="some" select="text()" />
<xsl:value-of select="concat($some,':')" />
        <xsl:for-each select="($value)/value">
<xsl:variable name="other" select="text()" />
        <xsl:if test="contains($other,$some)">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(text(),';')" />
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </h4>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>variable</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd/title">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(current(),'_'),':',current())" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As can be seen, I am still struggling a lot to get to that point where I would get my desired output. I am very much fed up with XSL's *constant* variables. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Link to Online XML Transformer:
https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html

Comment: Also, if someone says that I could have done it easily with templates, probably but I am still getting a hang of XSL itself, have not yet reached to point where I am good enough with the language to brute into XSL templating, still could not understand that.
And, we can also ignore the "Table" within the XSL file.

Comment: **1.** Your question is tagged as XSLT 1.0 (and so is your stylesheet) - but `distinct-values()` requires XSLT 2.0. --- **2.** This is a *grouping* problem. Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is best done using the Muenchian method - see: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html.

Comment: That is very helpful information Michael
@michael.hor257k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the result you mentioned in XSLT-1.0 (because the `distinct-values()` function is not available in XSLT-1.0), add the following key

```
<xsl:key name="titles" match="catalog/cd/title" use="substring-before(.,'_')" />
```

and then use it in your variables like this (This is call *Muenchian Grouping* as mentioned above):

```
<xsl:variable name="abc">
    <xsl:for-each select="/catalog/cd/title[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('titles',substring-before(.,'_'))[1])]">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'_')" /><xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('titles',substring-before(.,'_'))">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:text>;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

If you then output the variable with

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$abc" />
```

you will get the following result:

> Empire: Empire_Burlesque_something;Empire_Burlesque_other
> Home: Home_Empire_Burlesque

With this knowledge you can complete your task creating an HTML file.
You should probably change your output method to "HTML" too by adding

```
<xsl:output method="html" />
```

to the root element of your XSLT.

Comment: It was clearly stated to avoid comment for a +1 or thumbs or like which is why I did not. But I wanted to thank you, so there it is.
Since I am new, if there is way one can thank according to the defined please, please do let me know and I shall oblige.

Comment: For the questioner, clicking the accept arrow counts as "thanks, it helped best" if that is what you asked.